# Connect to guest WiFi automatically

Tags: iphone, wifi

In the place where I work, there is excellent wireless coverage, but it is a "guest" network...that means you can connect to the wifi hotspots (they all have the same name), but before you can begin browsing/checking email/doing any data transfer - you have to open up Safari and click a small button at the bottom of the usage agreement to be authenticated. From there on out it's just as if you were on any normal data network/wifi.

The problem is that it will not leave me authenticated for very long if my iPhone is in standby. Sometimes after authenticating, using the internet etc., and putting the iPhone to standby I re-open the iPhone within 2-3min or so, it stays logged in. However, most of the time it will require me to go back into safari, and attempt to browse to any webpage before presenting me again with the same agreement.

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically accept this agreement upon connection to wifi with a certain SSID. This would be a huge time saver, save a lot of battery power.

Comment: does the Safari asks you to save the credentials ?

Comment: iPhones turn off the radio when put in standby and the wireless controller at your company quite rightly severs the connection between your iPhone & the network when it turns off - it is a guest network, after all. The same happens on my school's guest network, but we have private SSIDs setup for faculty members & students which do not have such a restriction. Our devices authenticate to our AD via the controller and a Radius server. Your company needs to get a little more sophisticated with its wireless. DO other folks experience this as well?

Comment: It does not ask for credentials, simply an accept/decline policy. So i have to accept it before it will allow me full access. The same happens on my laptop. Kind of a pain.